# how do I query for rows that are missing a value?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Got a column family that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id uuid,
  order_id text,
  order_ts timestamp,
  product_category text,
  product_distributor text,
  store_state text,
  transaction_discount decimal,
  transaction_id text,
  transaction_qty int,
  transaction_total decimal,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

How do I query all rows that don't have `transaction_total`? Seems like it'd be simple (`ISNULL`) but that doesn't exist in Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

1. To be able to filter rows where a column is `NULL` that implies:

   1. the storage engine actually stores a value for that column
   2. the `NULL` is considered to be a **value** and not a marker of a missing value

   As a side note, there have been long discussions in the SQL space about the meaning, interpretation, and implications of the `NULL` marker-vs-value and its 3-value logic (see this [wkipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

Getting back to Cassandra:

1. Cassandra doesn't store missing values (so a `NULL` column will actually not exist -- there will be no marker, or flag, or value stored)
2. To avoid the `NULL`-is-it-a-value-or-a-marker problem you could use a default value (for this particular example it seems like setting `transaction_total` to -1 would make it clear that the value needs to be computed)

*Update*: posting the above got me thinking if there would be a way to introduce a `is_column_missing` operator (that would also not be a performance hog). Cassandra uses bloom filters to reduce the number of disk seeks -- the bloom filter will basically tell with certainty if a row is *not present* in a file. Unfortunately there's no per-row column index available to check the same sort of information, so basically C* would have to read all entries for a row in order to determine if a column is present or not. As you can imagine that would be terrible.

Comment: "filter rows where a column is NULL" -- not what I said, I asked for: how do I query for rows that are **missing** a value?. I'm aware that cassandra doesn't store missing values; do I have to store a default value to be able to query for empties? That seems silly.

Answer (score -1):

You can just check it `null` value. Like below:

```
select *  from data where transaction_total <> null
```

Check additinal information here [3783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3783)

Comment: `Bad Request: line 1:44 no viable alternative at input 'is'`

Comment: after the edit: basically the same result: `Bad Request: line 1:45 no viable alternative at input '>'`. You are clear that this is CQL not SQL, right?

Comment: Issue 3783 is for Cassandra 3.0 -- that's not out yet.

Comment: its a bit old thread, but this is not working on cassandra 3.0